# How to handle a basic form submission with http4s?

Tags: scala, http, http4s

I can't believe this isn't in the [http4s documentation](https://http4s.org/v0.20/), and the example code I was able to dig up online (after poking around long enough to discover the `UrlForm` class) is not working for me.

The relevant bit of code looks like this:

```
case req @ POST -> Root / "compose" =>
  req.decode[UrlForm] { ps =>
    println("ps.values: " + ps.values)
    val content = ps.getFirstOrElse("content",
      throw new IllegalStateException("No content given!"))
    // Do something with `content`...
  }
```

When submitting the associated form, the `IllegalStateException` is thrown. `ps.values` is an empty map (`Map()`).

I can see (using `println`) that the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, as expected, and I can see from my browser's Network tab that request "paramaters" (the encoded form values) are being sent properly.

Comment: I do not think that `UrlForm` class does what you think it does. You should define your own **case classes** representing the form format and then `decode` the request body as an instance of that class. - Take a look to [this](https://http4s.org/v0.21/entity/)

Comment: Judging by the code [found here](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.http4s.HttpService), for example, it would appear that `UrlForm` can be used to decode form-submitted data. However, I will try your suggestion and report back if I have any success.

Comment: What does the request body look like exactly?

Comment: The request body is a `x-www-form-urlencoded` (the format a browser uses to "`POST`" a form by default). If I generate a request using `curl` with `--data "content=hey"`, on the Scala end, I still see an empty `Map()`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that I had a filter (`javax.servlet.Filter`) in place that was calling `getParameterMap` on the `HttpServletRequest`. This was draining the `InputStream` for the request, and it was happening before the request got passed off to the servlet (`BlockingHttp4sServlet`) instance.

It seems to me the `BlockingHttp4sServlet` should raise an `IllegalStateException` (or something more descriptive) when it receives an `InputStream` with `isFinished` returning true. (I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/issues/3214) with the http4s project on Github.)